# send war to another job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've built two jobs in my jenkins instance:

1. Gradle job builds war task and generates a war file ready to be deployed.
2. Docker job builds a Docker image from a repository.

Both are working fine. However, the second one depends on the first one. So, Docker job needs to use the last war file generated by Gradle job.

How could I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parameterized job trigger` plugin to trigger sub jobs with parameter. You have to do the following to resolve above problem:

1. Create parent job which will have two sub jobs which you mentioned.
2. Then trigger first job and archive the artifacts which is `war` file.
3. Then pass last trigger build number of first job to second job and start that job. Use `Copy artifacts` plugin to copy `war` from first job with specific build number which was passed before starting.

This will resolve your problem!!!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Devavrata. I don't quite to understand dirst item. Why do I need to create a parent and two subsubjobs? Am not I able to create two jobs and send information between each others without a parent?

Answer (score 0):

Use a post build task for your first job (Gradle job), just cp the war file into the workspace of Docker job. Then configure Docker job  so that it does NOT clean workspace before build. And for the post build action, choose delete workspace after build. This will ensure you will only have the latest war file in Gradle job workspace. Also, you should use post build trigger, if your not using that already.

Good Luck!